# Postgres Slow Update in python psycopg2

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sql-update, psycopg2

In the table **ABC**, I have 60M records and 9-10 columns. I created index on a column which is **msg_id(PK)**.

I have another table which is **temp_ABC** which contains 1M records, also created index on a column which is **msg_id(PK)**.

now I have to update 2 columns of **ABC** table where ABC.msg_id = temp_ABC.msg_id then set **ABC.col_1='STATIC_VALUE_1'** and **ABC.col_2='STATIC_VALUE_2'**

Currently it is taking 11 minutes to update and I wanted to do it in 3-5 minutes. is it possible ?

query :

```
f""" update 
       {tlt_table_name} 
 set 
     "MATCH_STATUS"='MATCH',"FINAL_STATUS"='PENDING FOR PROCESSING' 

 from 
    {temp_match_report_table} as tm 
 where 
    {tlt_table_name}."HEAD_MSG_ID" = tm."HEAD_MSG_ID"  """
```

Explain result : [see explain result from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thhc7.png)

Comment: And how update statement looks like ?

Comment: Could you show us the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for the UPDATE statement? (by the way, this form of EXPLAIN will execute the UPDATE!)

Comment: I've updated the question. can you check ?